# PrimeFaces selectOneListBox

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonelistbox

I use JSF with Primefaces. When I use

```
<h:selectOneListbox>
```

all objects are listed correctly, but when I replaced h with p,

```
<p:selectOneListbox>
```

nothing works.

Where is the error? I have listed the code below.

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="cmbProvince1" value="#{mohController.current.superArea}" disabled="#{mohController.modifyControlDisable}" style="size:5;height: 200px;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mohController.dpdhsAreas}" var="p" itemValue="#{p}" itemLabel="#{p.name}" />
</p:selectOneListbox>

<h:selectOneListbox id="cmbProvince" value="#{mohController.current.superArea}" disabled="#{mohController.modifyControlDisable}" style="size:5;height: 200px;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mohController.dpdhsAreas}" var="p" itemValue="#{p}" itemLabel="#{p.name}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

Comment: Your code worked for me. Are you sure that the p:selectOneListbox value attribute is bound to a String, that String has a getter/setter in the backing bean, the value for the selectItems is bound to a List<String>, that has a getter/setter in the backing bean and the namespace at the top of the page is present and correct for PrimeFaces?

Comment: any chance that you got jquery js somewhere added manually ?

Comment: I have used javax.faces.model.DataModel as the backing property for the value. Not String. That may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the Type of the collection used is DataModel, which works fine with the JSF, but not with PrimeFaces. Changing the type to the List solved the issue.